# Visual studio code 2019 with SDL2 problems

Tags: c++

How to fix: The code execution cannot proceed because SDL2.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
I try run my project but it crazy!!

Comment: "Visual Studio" and "Visual Studio Code" are totally different software. Which one you are talking about is not clear, because there is "Visual Studio 2019" and "Visual Studio Code 1.62", for example, but no such thing as "Visual Studio Code 2019".

Comment: Where have you installed SDL2? Where is the SDL2 DLL files located? They need to either be in the `PATH` or in the same directory as the executable program file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to reinstall the entire Visual Studio. But you must note which components like C# C++ Unity etc you installed so that it would be easy for you to reinstall VS as fast as possible.

If this helps you then accept the question. :)